# How to get events in X11 child window?

Tags: linux, events, gtk, x11, gdk

I need to handle events (MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, KeyDown, KeyUp) in X11 child window. Parent of this child X11 window - GtkWidget, so I can't create main loop...

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[XGrabPointer](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html), [XGrabKeyboard](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabKeyboard.html)

If you want to grab events from a gtk widget, you can use [g_signal_connect](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect)().

```
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mChild), "button_press_event",
                     G_CALLBACK(BPHandler), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(mChild), "key_press_event",
                     G_CALLBACK(KPHandler), NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant find example without x11 main loop... And these functions don't take pointer to function...

Comment: No, GtkWidget is only parent window, but my x11 window is child to this parent...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you needs some sort of event pump, and being a child window on a shared X display connection means, it's tethered to the main event loop. Technically you could start a second thread with its own display connection and event loop. Unfortunately Xlib is not very thread safe, especially in that regard. You could do it with Xcb.

Another approach would be putting the child under custody of a separate process and use XEmbed.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe the second way (Xcb) may be useful.

Comment: How to use Xcb events without main loop?

Comment: @Alexander: You need some event loop. That's why I suggested using an additional thread and a separate display connection. It can't be done without some loop. Or you use XEmbed, which would probably be the most reliable method.

Answer (score 0):

[XSelectInput](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html)?